# What is the proper отчество for Cтанислау?

Tags: slavic, выбор-имени

I recently met someone named Станислау, and couldn't figure out what his children's отчество would be. I know that for Станислав it is obviously Станиславович, but "Станислауович" sounds awkward to me. I know that one (for male) generally adds -ович unless the name ends in -ь or -й, for which -евич is used. But is there an exception for this name? What is he correct отчество?

Additionally, is this name still used? I have never seen it before, outside of this one person and some textbooks.

Comment: This question has been answered, but in general names ending in -у would have patronymic ending in -увич, not -уович.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Станислау (Станіслаў to be precise) is a Belarusian version of name Stanislav.
Keep in mind that Belarusian "ў" is more like w, so it does not sound like "oo".

Let's not dive into political issues here, but de-facto in all three eastern European Slavic countries there's a tendency to translate name into local variant. 
Nobody says Павел Маккартни, but Павло Скоропадський is always Павел Скоропадский in Russian. The same with Станіслаў - we can theorize for a pretty long time about forms like Миколаевич, Станислауович, Олександрович, Володимирович etc. - de-facto these are translated.

So, the answer is - "Станиславович". This is in Russian.
Moreover, in Belarusian, by the way, patronymic [is](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%9E_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%88-%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%8D%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87) "Станіслававіч" - ў morphs into "в". 
So, no mystery here as well :)

Comment: Do you mean, that if a man's name is Джеймс, his son's patronymic will be Яковлевич?

Comment: @YellowSky is James a Ukrainian or Belarusian version or Яков? Obviously it is not. This is something I've explicitly mentioned in answer ("nobody says Павел Маккартни...")

Comment: In the "Кухня" sitcom, they do have a `Михаил Джекович`.

Comment: @shabunc well, actually, James *is* Яков in Russian/Ukrainian/Belorussian. But yes, nobody translates english names.

Comment: @ Yellow Sky it would be Джеймсович because we don’t Russify the name. Like the basketball player Katerina Novoseltseva. Her patronymic is Джоновна because her father’s name was John, and he was a foreigner (from Africa), so they didn’t Russify his name.

Answer (score 1):

Станислау (Stanislaw) is the Byelorussian spelling of Станислав. So, in Russian we get Станиславович/Станиславовна. Now, actually, please correct me if I’m wrong because I’m Uzbek, and really don’t know much about how Byelorussian names work. Now, actually, in Byelorussian we get Станiслававiч as the male отчество. I don’t know the female one.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that in words taken from the Russian language, 'v' is usually used, not 'w':

> Stanislav - Станислав
>
> Bankova street - Банковая улица (located in Ukraine).

The letter 'w' is more commonly used in Polish words.

In Russian, the letter 'W' can be converted to either 'В', 'Ю' or 'У':

> Stanislaw - Станилав
>
> Warsaw - Варшава
>
> Krakow - Краков
>
> Matthew - Мэтью
>
> Kanye West - Кани Вест (in the common people, for simplicty) , Канье Уэст (in wikipedia, among "grammar nazy" (those who really dislike grammatical errors, they are jokingly called so)
>
> Wikipedia - Википедия (you can't pronounce Уикипедия or Юкипедия)

As you can see the Russian language is full of exceptions :)